# Looking for a Cloud Storage Provider with Content Indexing Capabilities

Tags: collaboration, document-management, cloud-storage, document-indexing, search

I work for a small company (less than 25 employees) where most employees work from home. We currently uses JungleDisk as a way to provide shared storage to our users. It works great for most things but it lacks when it comes to search capabilities. Does anyone have any suggestions for a better alternative? In particular we're looking for these features:

1. Windows Explorer integration. The main thing we like about JungleDisk is that it creates a drive like any other Windows drive and allows the data to be organized as opposed to just searchable.
2. File name and file content searching. Jungle Disk doesn't offer either as far as I'm aware. Our contract is charged based on data that's accessed, so running individual indexing services on each client could increase our cost significantly.
3. Web interface in addition to the Windows Explorer integration
4. Data in transit is encrypted.
5. Cloud storage with 99.9% uptime.  We do have the capability and knowledge to host ourselves if there was a killer solution that had to be hosted ourselves, but prefer not to.
6. File tagging for indexing (in addition to the file content searching above).  This probably isn't critical, just a nice to have.
7. Active Directory Integration
8. Permissions settings so confidential documents can be limited to just those who need access.
9. Background upload - JungleDisk uses a local cache to allow you to work on files locally then syncs them as soon as changes are made in the background.
10. File locking - Jungle Disk isn't very good about this, probably because of number 9.

Numbers 1, 2, and 4 are the most critical to us in terms of features.

Is there a product out there that does what we're looking for?

Comment: Have you looked at SkyDrive/Office365?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Alfresco Cloud](http://www.alfresco.com/products/cloud):

1. Sync with your filesystem using desktop sync. Your changes get uploaded, you get remote changes, just like Dropbox.
2. All content is indexed: filenames, metadata, full-text of PDF, office documents, and many others.
3. Modern web interface called "Alfresco Share".
4. All exchanges are over HTTPS.
5. [Great uptime](http://status.alfresco.com/) though I don't have further statistics.
6. Tags and categories
7. Alfresco on-premise can be integrated with Active Directory, not sure about Alfresco Cloud
8. Permissions, roles, groups.
9. Yes when used together with desktop sync.
10. Yes, you can lock of file to edit it, and unlock it when you're done. An admin can remove a lock though.

Answer (score 0):

Perforce Commons:  [Link](http://www.perforce.com/commons)

1. Windows Explorer integration. The main thing we like about JungleDisk is that it creates a drive like any other Windows drive and allows the data to be organized as opposed to just searchable.  **Yes with on site, not sure about hosted, it does allow you to organize files how you want to**
2. File name and file content searching. Jungle Disk doesn't offer either as far as I'm aware. Our contract is charged based on data that's accessed, so running individual indexing services on each client could increase our cost significantly.  **Full search, cost is free up to 20 users, and is a per person license beyond that (its very reasonable)**
3. Web interface in addition to the Windows Explorer integration  **Yes**
4. Data in transit is encrypted.  **Yes**
5. Cloud storage with 99.9% uptime. We do have the capability and knowledge to host ourselves if there was a killer solution that had to be hosted ourselves, but prefer not to.  **Yes**
6. File tagging for indexing (in addition to the file content searching above). This probably isn't critical, just a nice to have.  **Program allows you to easily modify file meta-data (author, topic etc) They are also working on a formal tagging system**
7. Active Directory Integration  **Yes**
8. Permissions settings so confidential documents can be limited to just those who need access.  **Permissions can be as granular as you would like them to be, down to the person or file.**
9. Background upload - JungleDisk uses a local cache to allow you to work on files locally then syncs them as soon as changes are made in the background.**Not sure on this one...**
10. File locking - Jungle Disk isn't very good about this, probably because of number 9.  **Commons runs on the Perforce base version control software (their primary product) it is very good at version control**

[image]